# Assets loaded but not applied in rails 4

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, slim-lang

I've just created a test project and been reading about the assets pipeline. So far, the assets are being loaded but not applied, as if I go to `localhost:3000/assets/application.css` I see the style I've written but I don't see the rules applied to the DOM.

Rails version: 4.2.1
Ruby version: 2.2.0

The structure is the following:

```
app
--- assets
------ images
------ javascripts
------ stylesheets
------------ application.css
------------ todos.css
```

The content of `application.css` is the following:

```
/*
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
*/
```

The content of `application.js` the following:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

The rails APP is very simple, as it's just a model (`todo.rb`), the controller for that model (`todos_controller.rb`) with the following content:

```
class TodosController < ActionController::Base
  def index
    @todos = Todo.all
  end
end
```

Very simple, and for the view I'm using Slim templates with the following hierarchy:

```
app
--- views
------ todos
--------- index.slim
```

The content of `application.html.erb` is the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

And for the view:

```
.todos
  - @todos.each do |todo|
    .title = todo.title
    .content = todo.content
```

Is there about the assets pipeline I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename `index.slim` into `index.html.slim`.

P.S. convention over configuration

Comment: If it won't help, run 'rake routes' - and tell us the results

Comment: But if it helped you, let me know, please

Comment: I'm afraid it didn't work. Here is the dump of `rake routes` http://i.imgur.com/75JSZ5a.png

Comment: when you renamed 'index.slim' into 'index.html.slim', did you change the syntax?

Comment: To be sure that your 'application.html.slim' works well (rename application.html.erb, too) paste some test text inside the body

Comment: Also, it would be great to see your Gemfile.lock

Comment: Thanks. what about Gemfile? did you add both: gem 'slim' and gem 'slim-rails'? (don't forget 'bundle' command and restart server)

Comment: Okay, try 'rails c' and find your @todos. Are they present?

Comment: Yes they are, as the views are being rendered correctly, CRUD operations on models work perfectly, the only trouble seems to be the assets

Comment: So, if you put code from your 'index.html.slim' instead yield does it work?

Comment: I managed to solve the problem :). Thanks a lot for the help anyway. Posting the answer now

Answer (score 2):

The TodosController must inherit from `ApplicationController`, not from `ActionController::Base`

```
class TodosController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @todos = Todo.all
  end
end
```